# The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource-Client cert Authentication

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, client-certificates

Some of resources in my application require client certificate before accessing them, but not all of them. So I put them under url pattern "/secured/*"
 and added following lines to my web.xml

```html
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Secured</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>cert</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
<role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And I added the following lines to my servlet.xml

```html
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
               
               <Connector
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               port="8443" maxThreads="200"
               scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
               keystoreFile="placeholdertokeystorefile" keystorePass="placeholderforpass"               truststoreFile="placeholderfortruststorefile"  truststorePass="placeholderforpass"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But it works partially, namely when a user requests resources under "/secured/*" , browser prompts list of user certificates on the pop-up. But after choosing it, tomcat redirects 401 page(Unauthorised) and does not show resource. I even tried to implement simple custom realm  like

```
public class MyRealm extends NullRealm {

    @Override
    protected Principal getPrincipal(X509Certificate certificate) {

        return new GenericPrincipal(certificate.getSubjectDN().getName(),null,null);
    }

}
```

And referred it inside tomcat's conf/context.xml file(not sure this is the right place to put though) and jar file I put inside tomcat-home/lib/ folder.

But I am still getting "The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource."

Any idea how to resolve this issue? And generally, is it a good practise to handle this case with only one tomcat? Or should I use distributed architecture aka 2 tomcats should reside on the backend(one with clientauth=true and other one with clientAuth=false)

**UPDATE**: What I found on the net suggest to add usernames to tomcat-users.xml, but in my case this is simply not possible as we have many users, adding them all manually could create maintenance problem.

Comment: Which Tomcat version are you using ?

Comment: Tomcat 8.5.5 @EugèneAdell

Comment: Maybe try with a newer 8.5 version (8.5.45) ? There are other connectors than Http11NioProtocol that you are using, for example OpenSSL JSSE as detailed in the [SSL-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: You need to map users to roles in some way, either in the XML file as you suggest or you can use a database or a custom mechanism. The way this works is that the user's name is extracted from the certificate (the full CN is used) and then that is looked up in the realm to determine that users roles. As security constraints in JavaEE are specified as RBAC there is no way around this.